# lazyloading of data providers in testng

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to achieve lazy loading of data provider for my tests but it is not working . Below is my code snippet for factory annotated method:

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TF
{
    @DataProvider(name="TestInstances")
    public static Iterator<Object> testInstancesDP()
    {
        return new Iterator<Object>()
        {
            int counter=1;
            int MAX;
            {
                MAX=4;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return counter<=MAX;
            }

            @Override
            public Object next()
            {
                System.out.println("passing "+counter+" iterator instance");
                return new Object[] {counter++};
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                //TODO: IllegalOperationException
            }
        };
    }

    private int order;

    @Factory(dataProvider="TestInstances",dataProviderClass=TF.class)
    public TF(int order)
    {
        this.order=order;
        System.out.println("TF Instance created : "+order);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Iterator<Object> testDataProvider()
    {
        return new Iterator<Object>()
        {
            int counter=1;
            int MAX;
            {
                MAX=TF.this.order;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext()
            {
                return counter<=MAX;
            }

            @Override
            public Object next()
            {
                System.out.println("passing "+counter+" as DP");
                return new Object[] {"DP"+counter++};
            }

            @Override
            public void remove()
            {
                //TODO: IllegalOperationException
            }

        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider="testDataProvider")
    public void testStepExecutor(String str)
    {
        System.out.println("Test method execution : "+str);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown()
    {
        System.out.println("Tear Down: "+this.order);
    }

    /**
     * @return the order
     */
    public int getOrder()
    {
        return order;
    }
}
```

- **Actual Output:**

  passing 1 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 1
  passing 2 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 2
  passing 3 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 3
  passing 4 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 4
  [TestNG] Running:
    Command line suite

  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  Tear Down: 1
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  passing 2 as DP
  Test method execution : DP2
  Tear Down: 2
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  passing 2 as DP
  Test method execution : DP2
  passing 3 as DP
  Test method execution : DP3
  Tear Down: 3
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  passing 2 as DP
  Test method execution : DP2
  passing 3 as DP
  Test method execution : DP3
  passing 4 as DP
  Test method execution : DP4
  Tear Down: 4

  ===============================================
  Command line suite

  ## Total tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
- **Expected output**

  passing 1 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 1
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  Tear Down: 1
  passing 2 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 2
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  passing 2 as DP
  Test method execution : DP2
  Tear Down: 2
  passing 3 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 3
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  passing 2 as DP
  Test method execution : DP2
  passing 3 as DP
  Test method execution : DP3
  Tear Down: 3
  passing 4 iterator instance
  TF Instance created : 4
  passing 1 as DP
  Test method execution : DP1
  passing 2 as DP
  Test method execution : DP2
  passing 3 as DP
  Test method execution : DP3
  passing 4 as DP
  Test method execution : DP4
  Tear Down: 4
  [TestNG] Running:
    Command line suite

  ===============================================
  Command line suite

  ## Total tests run: 10, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

Is this a bug in TestNG implementation or lazyloading is not supported for Factory.. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Lazyloading of data provirder is not working for Factory because TestNG is currently invoking all factory methods before running tests.

Comment: As I can see it still works the same way. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Nope and I don't know if it will be possible to change it. But you can ask for the feature on the existing ticket https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/427